# spring transaction is failing jpa commits

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I have upgraded our application from spring 3.2 to 4.2 , java 7 to 8 . After that I could see several jpa, org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException, transaction rollback exceptions are logging due to this migration. As per the transaction framework these exceptions are valid, but why did not they appear in spring 3.2 application? Due to this lot of services are failing in my application and not sure if I did wrong configurations.

Comment: Perhaps modify your question by adding the source code around where the exception was thrown, and the exception output itself.

Comment: Unchecked exceptions are eligible for rollbacks in Spring transactions by default. You've to mark the ones as excluded or handle them manually, if current behavior is unexpected

Comment: @WildDev I understand that Unchecked exceptions are eligible for rollbacks in Spring transactions by default. But why did not they thrown with spring 3.2, started appearing after upgrading to 4.2. I have not modified any transaction/spring configurations  as part of the up gradation. Thanks.